# Ambiguous Match found to same line

Tags: ruby, regex, cucumber

My test started to fail recently. while working on a separate project. It says the same row and line is ambiguous to its self.

```
    Cucumber::Ambiguous: Ambiguous match of "Store test data for StoreSource to file":

    features/step_definitions/write_step_details_definitions.rb:143:in `/^Store test data for ([^"]*) to file$/'
    features/step_definitions/write_step_details_definitions.rb:143:in `/^Store test data for ([^"]*) to file$/'

    You can run again with --guess to make Cucumber be more smart about it
```

the line it is referring too is:

```
 And(/^Store test data for ([^"]*) to file$/) do |testSite|
   #Being Phased out
   env = FigNewton.base_url.downcase
   env.gsub!( /[\W_]+/,'' )

   path = env.upcase

   $testSite = testSite + '_'


   $fileName = GetFileData.getFileName path, $testSite, $TIME_STAMP
   puts "New File name: #{$fileName}"

   GetFileData.new()

   count = GetFileData.getRowCount $fileName

   data = "#{count + 1}) Test for #{testSite}."
   data = "\n" + data unless GetFileData.hasContent path, $testSite, $TIME_STAMP

   step "Write data to file data: #{data} at Path #{$fileName}"

 end
```

I have looked through the entire project and saw no similar or matching regex. Anyone have any idea what the issue really means. Its pointing to the same line twice. I'm not even sure what else to post to find

Comment: If you remove (temporarily) the step at line 143, does cucumber complain?

Comment: is it possible that you load the file twice?

Comment: I commented out every use to the call and it no longer complains. I also checked to see if something was referencing that file directly, but there was no reference anywhere.